# How to enable log4j in this Grizzly/Jersey application

Tags: log4j, jersey, grizzly

I'm not using any XML configuration and am doing everything at run time.

My application runs and Jersey my API works, but I'm not seeing any logs being written.  I expect to see something like `INFO: [MyApp] Initializing log4j from [classpath:environment-${MY_ENVIRONMENT}.properties]`
 when this application boots up to confirm it's seeing the log4j configuration.

I've avoided using `log4j.properties` since I want different logging configuration per my application's environment.

**How can I get this application writing logs via my log configuration?**

My main class is:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyServerFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;

...

protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
    ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.company.product.api.resources");
    Map<String,Boolean> features = rc.getFeatures();
    features.put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);

    return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //Without this, ApplicationContextProvider has no context
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

    //The only reason this is here is because I think I need it for log4j config
    WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("API", "/");

    //enable log4j configuration
    ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener");
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("log4jConfigLocation", "classpath:environment-${MY_ENVIRONMENT}.properties");

    //enable annotation configuration so we can avoid XML
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "com.company.product.api");

    //allow spring to do all of it's stuff
    ctx.addListener(ContextLoaderListener.class);

    HttpServer httpServer = startServer();

    System.in.read();
    httpServer.stop();
}
```

In `environment-production.properties`, all configuration is properly being used, except for **log4j**:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/var/log/productionApi/productionApi.log

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, should not overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true

# Set the DatePattern
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd-a

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example, you didn't call ctx.deploy(HttpServer).  If you don't do that, then the ServletContext listener you've defined won't be invoked (note:  it doesn't matter if you call deploy before or after the server has started).

Answer (score 0):

You may pass `log4j.configuration` system property to do the trick.

For example:

```
    java -Dlog4j.configuration=environment-production.properties
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm still seeing warnings about no log4j config